# Change Directory (cd) to Network Share (Windows XP) in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, network-shares

How do I navigate in the terminal to a Windows network share?

I can access the Windows work-group using the GUI but I would like to get there in bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking in `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.10 the paths were changed: http://serverfault.com/a/456854/102447

Answer (score 4):

You could install smbfs and mount a Windows network share using smbmount. This way you won't need to connect to the Winodows share with the UI before accessing it.

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
man smbmount
```

Answer (score 3):

Those share folders are supposed to be mounted at `/media`, so just do `ls /media` and find your windows share folder name, and you could just use that share folder `/media/something` as normal file system.

You could also check mount points with `df` command also.

Comment: Tried `ls /media` with `-lha` and found no network shares.  Also looked in `mnt` with no luck.